# What possible effects to include when running a Mixed Model, time variable and or lags for DV's and IV's?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lags, growth-model

I'm doing analyses in R on 5 repeated observations over a period of 5 years (repeated/random dv: 'amount of professional health care', repeated/random IV's: 'amount of social support' with several other random and fixed variables/covariates) Multilevel Analysis seems one of the (most) correct analysis to me.

1: My main research question is whether or not there is a relation between 'Health Care' and 'Social Support' how should i decide whether i should include lagged variables for DV and IV's or is this resolved when we control for Covariance Structure like AR1?

2: When using lags, don't we always loose the first row of data for each case/id? This means we loose 20% of the data when dealing with 5 rows of data for each id?

3: Do we call these kind of analysis always growth modelling when we include a 'time' variable when doing regressions?

4: Should I include (higher order) interactions  of the time variable to allow nonlinearity, since I expect no linear association between time and DV. Actually, I'm not interested in the effect of time at all, only about my main research question. Does anyone have any guidance, good article or book for figuring out what the best approach is for these kind of data when dealing with bivariate relations within persons? Maybe I should include time as a factor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You ask important questions, which I address below in turn.

> 1: My main research question is whether or not there is a relation between 'Health Care' and 'Social Support' how should i decide whether i should include lagged variables for DV and IV's or is this resolved when we control for Covariance Structure like AR1?

See this [recent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/627890/87305) Q&A on a very similar question about lagged DVs vs. alternative covariance structures.

> 2: When using lags, don't we always loose the first row of data for each case/id? This means we loose 20% of the data when dealing with 5 rows of data for each id?

Yes, you lose all the observations from the first time point. Assuming the same number of observations at each time point, that would be 20% of your observations.

> 3: Do we call these kind of analysis always growth modelling when we include a 'time' variable when doing regressions?

Typically, we call them growth models when we also include the continuous time variable as a varying (or random) slope such that each individual has their own starting point (intercept) and rate of change (slope through their data points).

> 4: Should I include (higher order) interactions of the time variable to allow nonlinearity, since I expect no linear association between time and DV. Actually, I'm not interested in the effect of time at all, only about my main research question.

If you are not interested in time, then you might consider including time as a categorical predictor, as you suggested in your very last sentence. This ensures no improper assumption about the shape of change in the DV over time and has the effect of estimating the association of interest as a within-time point estimate.

The issue you deal with when estimating bivariate change is that there is some sort of systematic change in both the key IV and the DV. If that is the case, then you need to account for it. This is easiest to do using structural equation modeling, but can also be [accomplished](https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/tutorials/growth-modeling-chapter-8-multivariate-growth-models-and-dynamic-parameters) in R with `nlme`. The same [book](https://www.pilesofvariance.com/) by Lesa Hoffman that I referenced in the linked Q&A devotes chapters 8 and 9 to this topic. I highly recommend it.